# Can Cognito Forms calculate rental inventory availability by date and other variables across multiple form submissions?

Tags: cognito-forms

I need to know if I can create a calculation(s) that will keep a running total across all form submissions of when certain products or services are selected on particular dates and allow me to create maximum allowances of those products and services by date so that I do not over book my ability to deliver on either the products or the services on any given date.

For example, I have 29 women's size medium bicycles and three different guided activities that will draw from that pool of equipment. I've got three guides who can each take 10 participants.  Low and behold, three 10 person bachelorette parties try to sign up for May 21 and they are all women's size medium.  I need calculations and ceilings in place that will disallow certain dates where equipment and/or human resources are already at their limit.  So in this example, the first two parties will be able to sign up with no problem, but the third party will be prompted to call us or select a different day.

Can Cognito forms do this? And if you know they can, how can I create these calculations?

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) does not currently support inventory limits.   This is on our 2016 roadmap and we are researching how to deliver this capability.

Check out this feature on our Idea Board:
https://trello.com/c/mxxJ71Vs/225-inventory-limits